# PHP $_POST is empty when posting hidden fields

Tags: php, forms, post

I have the following form that is dynamically generated:

```
<form action="index.php?route=module/print_wizard/showPrintSheet&amp;token=4ef5f4af6ba25d6096357fdb4809e819" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
    <input name="[print][6][1]" type="hidden" value="on">
    <input name="[print][6][3]" type="hidden" value="on">
    <input name="[info]" type="hidden" value="INV-GIS-00002-3">
    <input name="[layout_override][6][1]" type="hidden" value="">
    <input name="[layout_override][6][3]" type="hidden" value="">
    <input name="[bundle_override][6][1]" type="hidden" value="">
    <input name="[bundle_override][6][3]" type="hidden" value="">
    <input name="[run_id]" type="hidden" value="14040455">
    <button type="submit">Export</button>
</form>
```

My PHP code is:

```
var_dump($_POST);
echo "<HR>".$this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

I have done this a million times before and can not for the life of me figure out why my $_post array is empty.  I have changed my post to a get and all the fields and values are passing, but I need to use a post. Do I need to have one visible form element? Please help!

Comment: Can you add the actual generated form code? Which framework are you using?

Comment: Do you have a form tag? Does that form tag have a method="post"? Are your hidden input inside of that form tag?

Comment: How are you simulate POST request?

Comment: Are your inputs inside the form?

Comment: Are you sure you have set the form method to POST?

Comment: If you have zero visible elements (which should be no problem), I assume it's button-less. How are you posting the form then, with javascript? We have too little information to go on here.

Comment: Can you post the code for the form itself?

Comment: That's strange it deleted my html code from the question. Let me edit real quick

Comment: Very strange the code was in the question just not displaying. I resaved and it looks like its there now. Very simple form structure.

Comment: have you tried `<input type="submit" value="export">` instead of `<button ...>`?

Comment: I am actually using $('#form').submit(); in a script, but because of the error I replaced the script with a button. I will try the input tag now though

Comment: I think you are write your code with OpenCart.
Did you have some code before `var_dump($_POST);`?
All input hidden should work fine.

Comment: I am using opencart. Before var_dump I have only two lines:   $this->data['print_date'] = date('m-d-Y H:i:s'); $this->data['run_id'] = date('dmhi');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using valid names for your form fields:

```
<input name="[print][6][1]" type="hidden" value="on">
```

is not valid as it just has an array index but no name.

If you change it to for example:

```
<input name="print[6][1]" type="hidden" value="on">
```

it will work without any problems.

Comment: OMG I'm an idiot! Thank you so much! I was pulling my hair out.